# i want to change CLOB of size in my oracle tables

Tags: oracle, clob, maxlength

I have a table with CLOB column but I want to modify the CLOB of length >>
I executed this command "Alter table TableName (flddata CLOB length 100 Gb);
but i there is an error accorded "Invalid alter table option"
I want to increase the size of the field, how is that??
Thanks in advance

Comment: A CLOB column doesn't have a length the way a `varchar` does. You just store a bigger value if you need to increase it

Answer (score 0):

A clob column has no limit in the specification of the type. So, when you define a column as CLOB, it has no size associated the same as other string types ( char, varchar2 ).

However, the limit of what you can store there is defined by this:

CLOB    Maximum size: (4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE initialization parameter (8 TB to 128 TB)